# Get an blank image after updating the form detail

Tags: php

In this code when I navigate to the update form I get all the details as per database but when I update the form without selecting the image file it shows blank in the table.

```
if (isset($_POST['update_sub_categories']))
    {
    $file = $_FILES['Subcategory_image']['tmp_name'];

    this are the conditions for update images
    if (file_exists($file))
        {
        $errors = array();
        $maxsize = 2097152;
        $acceptable = array(
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/jpg',
            'image/gif',
            'image/png'
        );
        if (($_FILES['Subcategory_image']['size'] >= $maxsize) || ($_FILES["Subcategory_image"]["size"] == 0))
            {
            $errors[] = 'File too large. File must be less than 2 megabytes.';

            // code...

            }

        if (!in_array($_FILES['Subcategory_image']['type'], $acceptable) && (!empty($_FILES["Subcategory_image"]["type"])))
            {
            $errors[] = 'Invalid files type. Only JPG, GIF and PNG types are accepted';
            }
        }
```

Conditions end at this point
if no errors are found, the file will be uploaded

```
    if (count($errors) === 0)
        {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Subcategory_image']['tmp_name'], 'images/categories/' . $_FILES['Subcategory_image']['name']);
        $Subcategory_image = $_FILES['Subcategory_image']['name'];

        // code...

        $m->set_data('Category_id', $Category_id);
        $m->set_data('Subcategory_description', $Subcategory_description);
        $m->set_data('Subcategory_name', $Subcategory_name);
        $m->set_data('Subcategory_image', $Subcategory_image);
        $a = array(
            'Category_id' => $m->get_data('Category_id') ,
            'Subcategory_description' => $m->get_data('Subcategory_description') ,
            'Subcategory_name' => $m->get_data('Subcategory_name') ,
            'Subcategory_image' => $m->get_data('Subcategory_image') ,
        );
        $q = $d->update("sub_categories", $a, "Subcategory_id='$Subcategory_id'");
        if ($q > 0)
            {
            header("location:Manage_subcategories.php");
            }
          else
            {
            echo "Error";
            }
        }
      else
        {
        header("location:Manage_subcategories.php?msg=invalidfile");
        }
    }
```

So how can i solve this?
When i click on the submit button without selecting any image files it shows blank at the table and it does not show the image that is already available

Comment: You have to check first that image exists from form data then only you need to embed the `$Subcategory_image` otherwise not.

Comment: @Soahm - Did you get my comment? Let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: yaa i am facing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put this condition

```
    $Subcategory_image ="";
        if($Subcategory_id){
           $sql = $d->select("sub_categories", "Subcategory_id="$Subcategory_id);
if($sql->num_rows>0){
        $data=mysqli_fetch_array($sql); 
        $Subcategory_image = $data["Subcategory_image"];
}
        }
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["Subcategory_image"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check!=false){
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Subcategory_image']['tmp_name'], 'images/categories/' . $_FILES['Subcategory_image']['name']);
             $Subcategory_image = $_FILES['Subcategory_image']['name'];
             $m->set_data('Subcategory_image', $Subcategory_image);
            }
             $m->set_data('Category_id', $Category_id);
             $m->set_data('Subcategory_description', $Subcategory_description);
             $m->set_data('Subcategory_name', $Subcategory_name);
```

also assign existing image to $Subcategory_image before this condition so that if file control is empty it get old image else of making old image field empty in db table

Comment: bt how to assign that, maens in which way

Comment: make query to check to get if image already exits you've to check it record already exists or it's new record

Comment: i dont know how to do that, can u help me

Comment: still facing that problem, sir , i can provide u code, so if u can help

Comment: Yes sure, it will be helpful to solve problem if you provide code.

Comment: Also let me know if you are using any open source or simple pdo for db connection

Comment: how can i send u my files?

Comment: yaa i use db connection files

Comment: can you send me any of your select query method sample you are using? so that I can make existing image query according to that query because I don't know in which way you are using your select query

Comment: function select($table, $where='', $other='')
    {
        if($where != '')
        {
            $where= 'where ' .$where;
        }
        $select = mysqli_query($this->conn,"SELECT * FROM $table $where $other") or die(mysqli_error($this->conn));
        return $select;
    }

Comment: this is the method available in my dbconnect file for select query

Comment: <?php
if (isset($_POST['update_sub_category'])) {

    extract($_POST);
    $q=$d->select("sub_categories","Subcategory_id = '$Subcategory_id'","");
    $data=mysqli_fetch_array($q);
?>
 from this method update form is get initialize

Comment: can you show me what result or error its returning ?

Comment: the result is like i still don't get saved image after  visiting to update page and click on update  button, i still  to select image in update form for image in my table

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is because the image input is taking as null as uploading it to database .. add a additional condition as when there is no image input assign the previous image input to the variable